# Rub it in on me OR Rub it in me?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

I want to say this person likes to be sarcastic to me. Is it, "He always rubs it in on me" OR "He always rubs it in me"?

Comment: *Rubbing it in* is not sarcasm: it means bringing up the subject of a mistake or failure repeatedly or in a hurtful way.

Comment: “He always rubs it in me” means something ***very, very different*** from what you’re intending. I would highly suggest not using that unless you are very sure that kind of sexual activity is what you are trying to describe.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The expression does rather lend itself to *double entendre*.

Answer (score 6):

Neither. You could say; *"He's always rubbing it in."* You don't specify what he is rubbing 'it' into. Bear in mind; this is slang. Alternatively, if you wanted to describe that the actions of his sarcasm were making you frustrated you might say - "*He's rubbing me up the wrong way*".

This formulation shouldn't be used formally as it is colloquial slang.

Comment: I agree with your first point. for that +1. But I think there is a danger of mixing metaphors here. I don't thing 'rubbing up the wrong way' is part of the same figure of speech as 'rubbing it in'. If you wanted to draw attention to the fact that you were the victim of the 'rubbing it in' I would suggest *He's always rubbing it in with me (that I was caught by a speed camera)*

Comment: You're right; I suppose I was differentiating between two similar uses of the word which are taken to mean very different things.